# How to switch between view controllers on the iPad?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, ipad

Usually I've used NSNavigationController to switch between different view controllers smoothly. Now, on the iPad, I need a way to switch between view controllers, but am at a loss, since it seems that I cannot start a UINavigationController iPad app from Xcode. The only substitute I've found is SplitViewController -- I don't wish to display my app in this manner. In short, all I need is:

**NEED:** A way to smoothly transition (Switch) between UIViewControllers (the views therof?) from my application delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templates are just starting points to make initial configuration easier.  You can just as easily start with the View- or Window-based Application template and then reconfigure it however you like.

Though keep in mind that Apple has not made iPad an option on the Navigation-based Application template for a reason (transitioning the entire window in an iPad is discouraged in the user interface guidelines).